# How can I set values in a grid after to load the store?? EXTJS3

Tags: php, grid, extjs3

I'm working with EXTJS 3 version.

I need to replace or set values into a grid store.

I call and fill each row of the grid with a JSONStore, that use one param (ID) to obtain each field from the SQL Query in a PHP file.

I can fill only 2 fields of a row in the grid because the third and fourth field not exist in the DB and I need to set manually in the code.

Example of the Grid:

```
 row   field1   field2   field3   field4

       car     truck     percent    cost
```

car and truck are filled from the DB sending a param with JSON and obtaining theses 2 fields.

percent and cost does not exist in the DB, but I need to set that values in the code.

percent = 100 (this value will be default value when I make and action)

cost = someone textfield value in the form. example (20000 US)

The idea is: When I make click in a combo, I load the store and fill the field (now works field1 and field2), but field3 and field4 will be set without the store, otherway, complete this field in the store.

How can I set this values??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `convert` function of `Ext.data.field` ([Reference](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert))

[Running Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fom)